# 'at' command output on Mac

Tags: linux, mac, scheduled-tasks, at

I need to execute scheduled tasks with `at` command:

```
echo "VM-run.sh $1" | at 08.00 > at_output.txt  2>&1
```

I would have the output of VM-run.sh, but what I have instead is this output:

```
job 5 at Fri Sep 23 08:00:00 2011
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're echoing the output of `$ at 08.00` into `at_output.txt`.

Try this instead.

```
$ at 08:00
./VM-run.sh > at_output.txt
^D
```

Then you'll get a confirmation like this.

```
job 1 at Sat Sep 24 08:00:00 2011
```

**Edit:** Alternatively for shell scripts, you can restructure the command like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
./VM-run.sh > at_output.txt | at 08:00
```

Comment: I have to schedule the AT command in a script so I cannot input the AT from keyboard

Comment: @robob See edit. :)

Comment: I think it's the right answer :-) In the night I'll check and I'll give you the answer ok. Thanks a lot

Comment: I try to run "echo "VM-run.sh $1 > at_output.txt" | at 18.40" but nothing happens

Comment: You're echoing the string literal "VM-run.sh $1 > output.txt". What you want to do, from what I understand, is to run the `VM-run.sh` script and echo the output into the `at_output.txt`, which is taken care of by the `>` character in my solution.